# PHP binary counter with string representation

Tags: php, optimization, binary, char, counter

Can we improve complexity of this code?

How to simplify this counter to not degrade readability?

Is there simpler logical solution to achieve this?

I am trying to do binary addition on my own -- that is why I am using string.

```
$pattern = '00000000';                                                                                        
                                                                                                              
while ($pattern !== '11111111') {                                                                             
    $bit_arr = str_split($pattern);                                                                           
    $rev_arr = array_reverse($bit_arr);                                                                       
    $arr_ln = count($bit_arr) - 1;                                                                            
    $i = 0;                                                                                                   
                                                                                                              
    while ($i <= $arr_ln) {                                                                                   
        if ((int) $rev_arr[$i + 1] === 0 && (int) $rev_arr[$i] === 0) {                                       
            $rev_arr[$i] = 1;                                                                                 
            $i = $arr_ln + 1;                                                                                 
            break;                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                     
                                                                                                              
        if ((int) $rev_arr[$i + 1] === 0 && (int) $rev_arr[$i] === 1) {                                       
            $rev_arr[$i + 1] = 1;                                                                             
            $rev_arr[$i] = 0;                                                                                 
            $i = $arr_ln + 1;                                                                                 
            break;                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                     
                                                                                                              
        if ((int) $rev_arr[$i + 1] === 1 && (int) $rev_arr[$i] === 0) {                                       
            $rev_arr[$i] = 1;                                                                                 
            $i = $arr_ln + 1;                                                                                 
            break;                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                     
                                                                                                              
        if ((int) $rev_arr[$i + 1] === 1 && (int) $rev_arr[$i] === 1) {                                       
            $rev_arr[$i] = 0;                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                     
                                                                                                              
        $i++;                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                         
                                                                                                              
    $next_pattern = implode('', array_reverse($rev_arr));                                                     
    $pattern = $next_pattern;                                                                                 
    $second = 1000 * 1000;                                                                                    
                                                                                                              
    usleep(0.5 * $second);                                                                                    
                                                                                                              
    echo $pattern . PHP_EOL;          
    echo 'Decimal number: ' .  bindec($pattern) . PHP_EOL;                                                     
}
```

Comment: You really need to elaborate your question. What is the problem statement?

Comment: @nice_dev Thank you for pointing out. I will edit this ASAP.

Comment: You need to explain what does it do? Just print out binary representation of numbers from 1 to 255? If so, why have you used a string? Are you trying out binary addition on your own?

Comment: If your code is working as expected, but you would like to have it reviewed, try [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary addition is pretty straightforward.

```
0 + 0 = 0
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 1 = 0 with 1 carry(for the next MSB bit)
```

Keeping the above 4 operations in mind, we start the binary addition starting with `carry` as `1`, meaning adding `1` to current representation. Now, if the addition of the current bit with carry can be one of the possible results:

- `0` - So set current bit as 0
- `1` - So set current bit as 1
- `2` - So set current bit as 0 with carry as 1 for next bit

In the below code, [`ord`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) is used to get ASCII value for `0` or `1`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$pattern = '00000000';
$length = strlen($pattern);
$expected = 1;
while($pattern != '11111111'){
    $carry = 1;
    for($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i){
        $curr_digit = ord($pattern[$i]) - 48 + $carry;
        $pattern[$i] = $curr_digit != 1 ? '0' : '1';
        $carry = $curr_digit == 2 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    
    echo bindec($pattern),PHP_EOL;
}
```

Time complexity is linear in terms of number of bits in the pattern.